# Do magic items level up with me?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, character-advancement

If I acquire, for example, an Amulet of Life protection when I'm level 2 when its modifier is +1, does its modifier increase to +2 automatically when I reach level 7, or is that counted as a completely different item which I then have to "refind"? Is the answer the same for all other items and weapons in the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. If you have a Amulet of Protection +1, it stays an Amulet of Protection +1. You will have to find, buy, or make an Amulet of Protection +2 if you want that instead.

All items work this way. Although there are artifacts (such as the *Staff of Fraz-Urb'luu*) that can increase their enhancement based on other parameters, they are the exception rather than the norm.

Comment: As a side note, if anyone on your party have the Enchant Magic Item ritual, you can pay only the difference in price between the new and old levels to improve it. You can do that even with a rare tier magic item (that usually can't be created by this ritual).

Answer (score 0):

It is a completely different item that you can upgrade with the appropriate magic ritual (Enchant Magic Item). This happens to all items in the game, maybe except some artifacts that become more powerful as their owner grows.

Comment: Would you mind telling me which ritual that is? Enchant Magic Item?

Comment: @abv2 I think it is called Transfer Enchantment